# How to enable largefile support on Windows using mingw/autotools?

Tags: c, linux, windows, mingw, autotools

As the title says, i am trying to find a way to enable largefile support on a project which uses autotools. I am using the `AC_SYS_LARGEFILE` macro on the configure.ac file and it works fine on 64 bit Linux (by default) and 32 bit Linux. Now i ported the project so it can compile on Windows (32 bits) using mingw but sadly the `AC_SYS_LARGEFILE` doesn't work (for example off_t is 4 bytes while on Linux is 8 in both 32 and 64 bits and fopen/fstat isn't replaced by fopen64/fstat64).

Here is a testcase where i can reproduce one of the problems (off_t is 4 bytes):

configure.ac

```
AC_INIT([testcase], [1.0.0], [admin@example.com])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
# Support for large files in 32bit systems
AC_SYS_LARGEFILE
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Makefile.am

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS=-I m4

bin_PROGRAMS=testcase
testcase_SOURCES=testcase.c
testcase_CFLAGS= -std=gnu99 -O2
```

testcase.c

```
#include "config.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("sizeof off_t: %i bytes\n", sizeof(off_t));
    return 0;
}
```

to compile/run the testcase i am using the following:

```
mkdir m4
autoreconf --install
./configure
make
./testcase
```

Output on 64-bit Linux (used gcc/autotools)

```
sizeof off_t: 8 bytes
```

Output on 32-bit Linux (used gcc/autotools)

```
sizeof off_t: 8 bytes
```

Output on Windows 7 32-bit (used mingw-get to prepare the environment):

```
sizeof off_t: 4 bytes
```

Any ideas about what i can add/modify in the configure script so i can get largefile support on both platforms? Is this possible using mingw/autotools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switched to the mingw-w64 project who despite the name, have a 32bit compiler who has proper largefile support. I am not sure if is a bug or a limitation of the original mingw32 project since i couldn't find a source of this problem in other projects.

Configure output with host=i686-pc-mingw32

```
...
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... unknown
checking for _LARGE_FILES value needed for large files... unknown
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
...
```

Configure output with host=i686-w64-mingw32

```
...
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... 64
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
...
```

The 2nd one generates a 32bit executable who outputs the correct value. To put in short: the problem was in the compiler and not in autotools.

I am still interested in an answer of why the original mingw32 has this problem and if this issue is solvable.

Comment: I found it was mingw-w64 [r4036](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/code/4036) which added LFS.  You can see in `_mingw_off_t.h` that they set their own `off_t` which doesn't conform to the native Windows' `long` (always 32-bit), but therefore does allow `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` to work.